# WebAPI with Entity Framework, Code First: Doesn't generate correct Id of inserted object

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

**EDIT**: Updated post, still need help with this.

**Question is** Why is is not adding the user with correct ID?

I'm working with WebAPI and whenever I make POST request via Fiddler, it adds an user with the incorrect ID.

I've Entity Framework to auto generate and increment the ID of my POCO class (User) yet instead of adding the user with ID of 1, it now acts if there were users in the database already and just creates the User with ID of for instance 16.

I checked the tables in Visual Studios Server Explore, where I right click the table and choose **Show Table Data** and there's nothing.

I've tried to clean and rebuild the solution and checked if there was any users in the table but none.

This is my Connection string in the Web.config file:

```
 <add name="ConnectoDbContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=CONNECTO_f8dc97e46f8b49c2b825439607e89b59;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Connecto.mdf" />
```

I used a Code First approach to a new DB.

I've also checked Microsoft SQL Server 2012, SQL Server Management Studio where I see a DB named CWS.Models.ConnectoDbContext so I am assuming that is the same one. However I must admit I have experienced inconsistency, some times it would have old tables even though I didn't have them in my solution anymore.

In SQL Server Management Studio I have checked that the UserId is an Identity Column. In Visual Studio I also checked the UserId column and it says, `Is Identity: True`.

I did run the following `DBCC CHECKIDENT ("[User]", NORESEED);` both in Visual Studio and in SQL Server Management Studio.

SQL Server Management Studio returns:

```
Checking identity information: current identity value 'NULL', current column value 'NULL'. DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

Visual Studio returns:

```
Checking identity information: current identity value '16', current column value 'NULL'. DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

They are both returning something different which makes me believe that they're not "connected" as in, it's not the same DB?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

/twice

Comment: Is the ID column in the DB an identity column? If you've had data in their previously, which you've subsequently taken out, the database retains the previous generated Id, and will continue from there

Comment: @Psytronic Yes, it's an Identity column. How would I be able to fix that?

Comment: Are you sure ef is not connecting to different database than you do with server explorer?

Comment: @WiktorZychla I have no idea really. Is there any way I would be able to check that?

Comment: What is your connection string?

Comment: @WiktorZychla I added them in my post above. In my App_Data folder in Visual Studio is shows the "Ball.mdf" file so I assume it's alright as it is.

Comment: Could it be that your datacontext name is NOT BallDbContext so that the website is actually writing to the default database? Also, the second connection string is missing Initial Catalog. Could this be an issue?

Comment: @WiktorZychla I commented out the default connection string and it's still the same issue and the names seem to be fine. I am not sure if that would cause an error. I pretty much reused the connection string from this [guide](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-model),scroll down to bottom, and simply changed the names etc for my needs.

Comment: What if you do not attach the db file but rather connect to a fixed database at the server? Just remove the attachdbfile and introduce initial catalog to your connection string. The database should be created with the structure by ef if you have it configured to do so.

Comment: @WiktorZychla What should I type then into the Initial catalog? Should I just leave it empty?

Comment: Whatever if the database is to be auto created. On the other hand, if you create the database manually, type its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to [re-seed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) the identity column:

`DBCC CHECKIDENT ("[TableName]", NORESEED);`

Be wary of doing this if you have data in there in other instances (could lead to duplicate keys later on).

Comment: I am not sure where I would need to paste or use this line of code. Would I be able to do it in the Package Manager console? I am using LocalDB.

Comment: Do you have SQL Management studio? Looks like you can/could connect through SSMS http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/10/27/net-framework-4-now-supports-localdb.aspx

Comment: I just executed it and it gave me an error saying `'User' does not contain an identity column.` When I checked it it SSMS the Identity field is empty and I can't write in it. However in Visual Studio when I check the `UserId` in table `User` it says `Is Identity: True`. Kinda weird...